# Firebase authen robo stuck with gmail sign in

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-test-lab

When i create an Android app for my phone i manage to login with gmail but when the robot try it goes to checking info not in selecting account....
I tried it with release and with debug and still the same.
I also tried it on multiple phones from firebase but i get the same result every times.
Here what the robot see
Note that the first time i tried it works but after that the robot cannot connect to my app.

[image: stuck]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the pb and i will give you the explanation in case of someone came into the same pb

It was because of the SHA-1 key and the sign of the application
It is a bad practice to do that with the real values : [image]

So i used fake one in order to test proguard and stuff. But when looking for the SHA1 key i used sign report on Android Studio => it generate me the fake Sha1
This is why the bot could not connect to my application